# When and why did “mess” come to mean an untidy condition?

Tags: etymology, latin

According to numerous [dictionaries](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mess) *mess* comes from the past participle of the Latin *mittere* meaning “to send”, because it was what was sent to the table.

Indeed, many uses of *mess* seem to jibe with this origin: *mess of beans, mess hall, messmate, mess kit*, and so on. The biblical *mess of pottage* has its own meaning; still it refers to Esau’s meal.

But the most common current meaning of *mess* appears to have nothing to do with food. So when and why, or at least how, did English *mess* come to mean “an untidy condition”?

Comment: "numerous dictionaries" Here are two." from Late Latin missus course at a meal, from missus, past participle of mittere to put, from Latin, to send." -Miriam-Webster

Comment: Oops hit "enter" by accident. "use of ppt. of L. mittere to send" The Random House College Dictionary

Comment: You can cut-and-paste.

Comment: @Airymouse You should add that to the question itself.

Comment: Both comments and questions can be edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recently updated entry in *OED Online* [*OED Third Edition* (September 2001) - fully updated; *OED Online* version September 2016] does not distinguish the etymology of 'mess' in the sense of

> **I.** A portion of food, and related senses.
>   **1. a.** A serving of food; a course; a meal; a prepared dish of a specified kind of food. Also *fig.* Now *hist.* and *Eng. regional* (except as merging into sense 2a).
>
> <sup>Figurative uses of this sense (for example, quots. 1570, a1764)
>   are often indistinguishable from the more pejorative senses 2c and
>   3a.</sup>

["mess, n.1". *OED Online.* September 2016. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/117092?rskey=lnyOAS&result=1&isAdvanced=false (accessed September 18, 2016).]

from the etymology of 'mess' in the sense of

> **2. c.** An unappetizing, unpalatable, or disgusting dish or concoction; an ill-assorted mixture of any kind, a hotchpotch.

(op. cit.)

or from 'mess' in the sense of

> **3. a.** *fig.* A situation or state of affairs that is confused or presents numerous difficulties; a troubled or embarrassed state or condition; a predicament.

(op. cit.)

For all three senses (and others, including "**3. b.** A dirty or untidy state of things or of a place; a collection of disordered things, producing such a state" [op. cit.]), the etymology given is

> **Etymology:** < Anglo-Norman *mes, mees, messe,* Old French *mes* portion of food (mid 12th cent.; Middle French, French *mets* dish, food) < post-classical Latin *missus* portion of food, course of a meal (4th cent.), spec. use of classical Latin *missus*, lit. ‘sending’....

(op. cit.)

Notwithstanding a variety of more or less poorly-considered folk etymologies, the derivation of the senses of 'mess' is not to my knowledge controversial. Senses I3a and I3b, for example, developed from figurative use of sense I2c, which itself reflects pejorative uses of sense I1a.

Answer (score 9):

The answer lies in convergent evolution. These are not the same word, and merit two distinct entries in any dictionary worthy of that name.

The version of *mess* that derives from [Latin *mittere*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mitto#Latin) meaning to send or put (think English *missive, mission, Mass*) is today used mostly [in a military context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mess), but was once also used for Roman Catholic rite. The Wikipedia article says:

> The root of *mess* is the Old French *mes*, "portion of food" (cf. modern French *mets*), drawn from the Latin verb *mittere*, meaning "to send" and "to put" (cf. modern French *mettre*), the original sense being "a course of a meal put on the table"; cfr. also the modern Italian *portata* with the same meaning, past participle of *portare*, to bring. This sense of mess, which appeared in English in the 13th century, was often used for cooked or liquid dishes in particular, as in the "mess of pottage" (porridge or soup). By the 15th century, a group of people who ate together were also called a *mess*, and it is this sense that persists in the "mess halls" of the modern military.

In contrast, [the **other** word *mess*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mess#Etymology_2) for, as you put it, an untidy condition, is more likely related to the verb *to muss* as in mussing up someone’s hair and may according to Wiktionary be a corruption of a Middle English verb *mesh* meaning to mash.

Comment: I'm surprised that Wiktionary seems better than AHDEL, Collins etc here. They don't even register homonymy. / The [citation needed] flag as per Wikipedia is a fine idea.

Comment: Unlike a lawyer, I never ask a question to which I do know the answer, but in defending my sweeping " according to numerous dictionaries," I came across an alternative answer." from late Latin missum something put on the table past participle of mittere send, put The original sense was a serving of food, also a serving of liquid or pulpy food, later liquid food for an animal; this gave rise (early 19th century) to the senses unappetizing concoction and predicament, on which sense 1 is based.  Oxford English Living Dictionary (on line.) Of course sense 1 is untidy condition.